# Trying to print after and before character from a string

Tags: python

In python, I'm trying to extract 4 charterers before and after '©' symbol,this code extracts the characters after ©,can anyone help printing the characters before © (I don't want the entire string to get print,only few characters)

```
import re
    html = "This is all test and try things that's going on bro Copyright© Bro Code Bro"
    if "©" in html:
        symbol=re.findall(r"(?<=©).+$",html,re.M)
        print(symbol[0][0:100])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a **regex only** solution to get the 4 characters before and after the ©

```
import re

text = "This is all test and try things that's going on bro Copyright© Bro Code Bro"

print(re.findall(".{4}©.{4}", text))
```

Output:

```
['ight© Bro']
```

Comment: @Pandsh Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
html = "This is all test and try things that's going on bro Copyright© Bro Code Bro"
html = html.split("©")

print(html[0][-4:])
print(html[1][:4])
```

Output :

```
ight
 Bro
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way :

```
if "©" in html:
    pos_c = html.find("©")
    symbol = html[pos_c-4:pos_c]
    print symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

Use search to get index and then slice/dice the string as you like

```
symbol=re.search(r"(?<=©).+$",html).start()
```

The above line give you the index of the match , in this case 63

Use

```
html[symbol:symbol+4] for post and html[symbol-4:symbol] for pre.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use python built in function split() to solve the problem.

`html = "This is all test and try things that's going on bro Copyright© Bro Code Bro"
html = html.split('©')`

Comment: He said `I'm trying to extract 4 charterers before and after '©' symbol` your solution does not provide this.